UE4 4.27 on Mac in 2024/2025
Premise: Hello, I want to point out that I'm not expecting much results regarding this issue because I understand that there are many newer versions of Unreal Engine that are recommended, but I'm still going to ask about this because finding a solution would be nice for me.
When I got access to my Unreal Engine 4.27 project I really wanted to try it and be able to work on it again. So, I installed UE4.27 with the Epic Games launcher and, while the engine works fine apparently, there are many errors I get while building my project, regardless of the platform or the project whatsoever. Here's the part of the log that I believe is the most crucial to understand the real issue:
...Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/IsTriviallyCopyAssignable.h:13:17: error: builtin __has_trivial_assign is deprecated; use __is_trivially_assignable instead [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-builtins]
13 |         enum { Value = __has_trivial_assign(T) };
|                        ^
(and other errors regarding deprecated features)
From what I understand, the Engine still uses obsolete and deprecated features in its code. I use a Mac and I have Xcode 16.
The recommended version of Xcode for UE4.27 is Xcode 12.4, but it is not supported anymore on the latest version of macOS.
Short summary of the issue: Unreal Engine 4.27 requires Xcode 12.4 to be compiled but such version is not supported on newer versions of macOS
Is there a way to successfully build and use Unreal Engine 4.27 on the latest versions of macOS?
Or is there really no fix at all and I have to upgrade my project to Unreal Engine 5, which I assume works with the newest versions of Xcode?
I had to deal with these errors multiple times.
At first, I only found them while exporting the game.
To fix that I just added some additional arguments in MyProject > Intermediate > Source > MyProject.Target.cs by adding this line:
AdditionalCompilerArguments = "-Wno-error -Wno-deprecated-builtins";
and it does work when I need to just export the game.
But I didn't want to work with a "broken and unstable engine" that only manages to stand thanks to a few arguments in the temporary target.cs script.
At that point, I thought it would be a good idea to build UE4.27 from source.
I cloned the repository, ran "Setup.command" and "GenerateProjectFiles.command".
When I opened Xcode to first build the ShaderCompileWorker, I immediately got errors. And guess what, the exact same errors I had been encountering.
I tried editing the source personally and had success with some of them. But even though I have some experience in C, C++ and writing headers, some of the errors were simply much more difficult for me to fix personally.
Are there any other ways to get rid of the errors without downgrading Xcode?
Does anybody know if Epic Games will revise the code of Unreal Engine 4.27 in the future to make it work with newer versions of Xcode (and Visual Studio as well possibly for people on windows)?

old stuff doesn't get updates. you are on your own.

If there hasn't been any updates for 3 years, I wouldn't bet on getting any after 4 years.
